# manners of collection

Tags: probability, foundations

I encountered idea of considering Sample space $\Omega$  as collection of function so far as I saw.

Can you show the proof of thesis $x \neq \{x\}$?
In a book I saw this thesis is included in context of Russell's paradox.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $x$ is any non-set object, the fact that $x \ne \{x\}$ is trivial.

Most certainly, if $x$ is a set with $|x| \ne 1$, you also have $x \ne \{x\}$ since the cardinalities differ.

The final case is $x$ is a set with cardinality $1$, i.e. $x = \{a\}$. Can you prove that $\{a\} \ne \{\{a\}\}$?

Comment: Can you? You delegate the one actual part of the proof, where one needs to appeal to the axiom of foundation as if it's *that* simple. Try to prove it yourself. You will quickly find that the proof works only if you assume that $x\neq\{x\}$. That's circular.

Comment: @AsafKaragila i do not have experience with the axiom of foundation, but i thought one could use the induction on the levels of indirection of the set. In other words, clearly $a \ne \{a\}$ if $a$ is not a set, and then inductively assuming this works for $n$ levels, prove that it works for $n+1$ -- why is this problematic? Sorry to bother you with a beginner's question, but the topic interests me

Comment: @AsafKaragila I upvoted your answer in the linked question, but I still don't understand why my primitive proof in the above comment does not work

Comment: The problem is that without the axiom of foundation you can't prove this by induction on rank. There is no notion of rank. So pathologies like $x\in x$ become possible.